# Why code sample from neo4j python drive official documentation does not work?

Tags: python, docker, neo4j, cypher, jupyter-lab

I'm currently working on a project where I need to build and display graphs. I am going to do it using neo4j but I have trouble running code sample from official doc.

- I'm using neo4j python driver from a jupyter lab notebook running inside a docker container.
- neo4j is running on another docker container
- both are in the same docker-compose and started at the same time

here is the link to the doc : https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/
I'm trying to execute the first code sample (Quick Example -> Creating nodes)

I'm using the same neo4j driver version than in the doc (4.1)

Here is the error I get :

```
CypherSyntaxError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I' (line 1, column 57 (offset: 56))
"CREATE (a:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(f:Person {name: $friend}) WHERE a.name = '$name' RETURN f.name AS friend"
                                                         ^}
```

To me it sounds like syntax won't allow to use keyword 'WHERE' together with 'CREATE' but I have a very poor experience with cypher for now. Anyways I took the example from official doc and it is not working do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's a lot cleaner to create your nodes first, and then your relationships after. So here's what I would recommend:

```
CREATE(:Person{name:$name});
CREATE(:Person{name:$friend});

MATCH(a:Person{name:$name})
WITH a
MATCH(f:Person{name:$friend})
CREATE(a)-[:KNOWS]->(f);
```

Finally, if you're doing a query, you could do something like this:

```
MATCH(a:Person{name:$name})-[:KNOWS]->(f:Person{name:$friend})
RETURN f.name AS `friend`
```

I've not tested this out, and there may be syntax errors, particularly with the `$name` and `$friend` variables, but this overall structure would, I think, work better for you.